# Group / Merge Columns Yii2 Gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

How can you merge one or more columns in a gridview?

I am currently using Kartikv Gridview but don't want to create an additional footer / header.

With a normal table this would be achieved with colspan

I want to merge the below "OD" in column 2 with the 4 columns on the right with just "OD" centered

[image: grdiview]

Current GridView:

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $fixtures,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'header' => 'Match Date',
            'value' => function($data){
                return date("d M Y", strtotime($data['fixtureDate']));
            }
        ],
        [
            'header' => 'Home / Away',
            'value' => function($data){
                return $data['homeAway']
            }
        ],
        [
            'contentOptions' => function($data){
                return $style['class'];
            },
            'value' => function($data){
                if($data['homeAway'] == 1 || $data['homeAway'] == 0){
                    return $data['homeScore'];  
                }
            },
        ],
        [
            'value' => function(){
                return 'vs';    
            }
        ],
        [
            'value' => function($data){
                return $data['awayScore'];
            }
        ],
        [
            'header' => 'Against',
            'value' => function($data){
                return $data['awayTeamName'];
            }
        ]
    ],
    'summary' => false,
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true
]); ?>
```

Comment: Please show your gridView code ..

Comment: Anyone got an answers to this one please

Comment: I have posted an answer hope is useful

Answer (score 1):

This topic is a bit old, but you can merge header cells like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider'=> $fixtures,
'columns' => [
    [
        'header' => 'Match Date',
        'value' => function($data){
            return date("d M Y", strtotime($data['fixtureDate']));
        }
    ],
    [
        'header' => 'Home / Away',
        'value' => function($data){
            return $data['homeAway']
        },
        'headerOptions' => [
            'colspan' => 3,
        ]
    ],
    [
        'contentOptions' => function($data){
            return $style['class'];
        },
        'value' => function($data){
            if($data['homeAway'] == 1 || $data['homeAway'] == 0){
                return $data['homeScore'];  
            }
        },
    ],
    [
        'value' => function(){
            return 'vs';    
        }
    ],
    [
        'value' => function($data){
            return $data['awayScore'];
        }
    ],
    [
        'header' => 'Against',
        'value' => function($data){
            return $data['awayTeamName'];
        }
    ]
],
'summary' => false,
'responsive'=>true,
'hover'=>true
]); ?>
```

In the headerOptions parameter if you provide any html tag attribute, it will be applied, like colspan, class, style, etc...

I hope it will help for some who finds this question.

Answer (score 0):

could be you need this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider'=> $fixtures,
  'columns' => [
      [
          'header' => 'Match Date',
          'value' => function($data){
              return date("d M Y", strtotime($data['fixtureDate']));
          }
      ],
      [
          'header' => 'Home / Away',
          'value' => function($data){
              return $data['homeAway']
          }
      ],
      [
          'header' => 'Home / Away',
          'value' => function($model){

             if($model->homeAway == 1 || $model->homeAway == 0){
                  return $model->homeAway . ' ' . $model->homeScore . ' vs ' . $model->awayScore . ' ' . $model->awayTeamName;  
              }  else {
                  return $model->homeAway . ' '  . ' vs ' . $model->awayScore . ' ' . $model->awayTeamName; 
              }
          }
      ],      

  ],
  'summary' => false,
  'responsive'=>true,
  'hover'=>true
]); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but this is only going to create content in one cell and not actually merge cells like when using colspan in html

Comment: Then you want a colspan in header only ?

Comment: Not really. The grid needs to stay as is but where OD or cup match to span the cells in the row over 5 cells

Comment: Anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: I take its not possible to do what I'm trying to do then.